# Calcular las horas nocturnas en php

Tags: php

estoy embarcado en una aplicación de gestión del personal, y necesito calcular las horas que un trabajador está en horario nocturno (desde las 22:00 a las 06:00). Es un programa para controlar las horas trabajadas y tiene que figurar la duración de la jornada (lo cual es muy fácil con `$inicio->diff($fin);`) pero debe también indicar del tiempo trabajado cuantas horas ha trabajado en horario nocturno.
Tengo dos campos datetime en una base de datos:

```
$inicio = new datetime('2019-02-01 00:35:00');
$fin    = new datetime('2019-02-02 08:42:00');
```

Las horas de inicio y final pueden ser variable, es decir los horarios de entrada y salidas pueden ser diferentes o ambos pueden estar en horario nocturno, o uno solo o ninguno, (no se si me explico). Muchas gracias por adelantado.

Comment: ¿Y como verificas las horas trabajadas por el personal?

Comment: es decir buscas calcular la diferencia entre $inicio y $fin ?

Comment: Si es de la diputación, conozco a gente que te agradecerá que soluciones ese problema 

Comment: Las horas se almacenan en la base de dato mediante un lector. Cada trabajador tiene su tarjeta para fichar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

después de darle vueltas y vueltas, creo que dí con la solución. Para lo que necesito me funciona, pero claro soy un "pringaillo" en esto del php y seguro que algún gurú lo haga mejor con 4 lineas de código, pero como no es mi caso lo solucioné así, por si a alguien le sirve de ayuda. De todas formas muchas gracias a todos los que se han molestado en ayudarme. Estaré por aqui por si puedo ayudar a otros. Gracias!

```
/* 
        Inicio y Fin el mismo día:
            - 07:00  a 15:00 E y S mayor que 06:00 y menor que 22:00
            - 00:00  a 05:00 E y S menor que 06:00
            - 03:00  a 11:00 E menor que 06:00 y S mayor que 6:00 y menor que 22:00
            - 15:00  a 23:00 E mayor que 06:00 menor que 22:00 y S mayor que 22:00

        Inicio y Fin dias diferentes:
            - 23:00  a 07:00
            - 21:30  a 05:00
            - 22:00  a 05:00
    */
    $he = new datetime('2019-01-01 21:00:01');
    $hs = new datetime('2019-01-02 05:59:59');


    $inicio_noche   = new datetime($he->format('y-m-d').' 22:00:00');
    $fin_noche      = new datetime($hs->format('y-m-d').' 06:00:00');
    $medianoche     = new datetime($hs->format('y-m-d').' 00:00:00');

    echo 'Entrada: '.$he->format('H:i:s').'<br/>';
    echo 'Salida: '.$hs->format('H:i:s').'<br/>';
    if ($he->format('d') == $hs->format('d')) {
        echo 'Mismo dia <br/>';
        if ($he->format('H:i:s') >= $medianoche->format('H:i:s') && $hs->format('H:i:s') <= $fin_noche->format('H:i:s')) {
            $diff = $he->diff($hs);
            echo 'E mayor que 0 S menor que 6<br/>';
            echo $diff->format('%H:%i:%s');
        }
        if ($he->format('H:i:s') < $fin_noche->format('H:i:s') && $hs->format('H:i:s') > $fin_noche->format('H:i:s')) {
            $diff = $he->diff($fin_noche);
            echo 'E menor que 6 S mayor que 6<br/>';
            echo $diff->format('%H:%i:%s');
        }
        if ($he->format('H:i:s') > $fin_noche->format('H:i:s') && $hs->format('H:i:s') > $fin_noche->format('H:i:s')) {
            $diff = $he->diff($fin_noche);
            echo 'E mayor que 6 S mayor que 6<br/>';
            echo '00:00:00';
        }
    }

    if ($he->format('d') != $hs->format('d')) {
        echo 'dia distinto <br/>';
        if ($he->format('H:i:s') >= $inicio_noche->format('H:i:s') && $hs->format('H:i:s') <= $fin_noche->format('H:i:s')) {
            $diff = $he->diff($hs);
            echo 'E mayor que 22 S menor que 6<br/>';
            echo $diff->format('%H:%i:%s');
        }
        if ($he->format('H:i:s') < $inicio_noche->format('H:i:s') && $hs->format('H:i:s') <= $fin_noche->format('H:i:s')) {
            $diff = $inicio_noche->diff($hs);
            echo 'E menor que 22 S menor que 6<br/>';
            echo $diff->format('%H:%i:%s');
        }
        if ($he->format('H:i:s') < $inicio_noche->format('H:i:s') && $hs->format('H:i:s') > $fin_noche->format('H:i:s')) {
            $diff = $inicio_noche->diff($fin_noche);
            echo 'E menor que 22 S mayor que 6<br/>';
            echo $diff->format('%H:%i:%s');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrias usar el **diif**:

```
$inicio = new datetime('2019-02-01 00:35:00');
$fin    = new datetime('2019-02-02 08:42:00');
$diff = $inicio->diff($fin);
echo $diff->h .' horas '. $diff->i . ' Minutos ' . $diff->s . ' Segundos';
```

Finalmente tu resultado seria:

```
8 horas 7 Minutos 0 Segundos
```

para mayor detalle:
[diif Php](https://programacion.net/articulo/calcular_la_diferencia_entre_dos_fechas_con_php_1566) espero te sirva y suerte..!!

Comment: Gracias, voy a mirar el enlace.

Answer (score 0):

para calcular la diferencia entre tus dos variables (inicio y fin) debes utilizar [DATEDIFF](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date-diff.php)

```
   <?php

    $inicio = new datetime('2019-02-01 00:35:00');
    $fin    = new datetime('2019-02-02 08:42:00');


    $interval = date_diff($inicio, $fin);
    var_dump ($inicio);
    echo  '<br>';
    var_dump ($fin);
    echo  '<br>';
    echo  '<pre>';
    var_dump($interval);
    echo '</pre>';
    ?>
```

esto te imprime un objeto `DateInterval`

donde `h` son las horas e `i` son los minutos.

```
object(DateInterval)#3 (15) {
  ["y"]=>
  int(0)
  ["m"]=>
  int(0)
  ["d"]=>
  int(1)
  ["h"]=>
  int(8)
  ["i"]=>
  int(7)
  ["s"]=>
  int(0)
  ["weekday"]=>
  int(0)
  ["weekday_behavior"]=>
  int(0)
  ["first_last_day_of"]=>
  int(0)
  ["invert"]=>
  int(0)
  ["days"]=>
  int(1)
  ["special_type"]=>
  int(0)
  ["special_amount"]=>
  int(0)
  ["have_weekday_relative"]=>
  int(0)
  ["have_special_relative"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

Entonces, para calular las horas de trabajo en horario nocturno debes especificar el final del turno de noche.

```
$finTurno    = new datetime('2019-02-02 06:00:00');
$horas_trabajadas = date_diff($inicio, $finTurno);

var_dump($horas_trabajadas->h); //5 horas
```

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas dadas tan rapidamente y haberos tomado la molestia de ayudarme, Muchas gracias. El tiempo trabajado lo calculo facilmente con la instrucción $intervalo = $inicio->diff($fin); Hasta ahí es facil, lo que necesito saber es como calcular el tiempo que trabajan en horario nocturno. El $inicio y el $fin pueden ser variables en cambio el horario nocturno es constante (de 22:00 a 06:00), pero como contabilizo si trabajan por ejemplo de 21:00 a 05:00, o de 00:00 a 08:00 o de 07:00 a 15:00 (en ese caso no hay horas nocturnas). Gracias otra vez.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar hacerlo de esta manera:

```
$inicio = new datetime('2019-02-01 00:35:00');
$fin    = new datetime('2019-02-02 08:42:00');

$intervalo = $inicio->diff($fin);

echo $intervalo->format('%H horas %i minutos %s segundos');
```

Así calculas las *horas*, *minutos* y *segundos*, que hay de diferencia entre `$inicio` y `$fin`

Espero que te sirva. Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo que busco es como contabilizar las horas que han trabajado de 22:00 a 06:00. Las horas de inicio y fin pueden ser muchas, pero las que necesito contabilizar es del $intervalo, cuantas son en horario nocturno. Gracias.